# What is the Lewis Structure for CH3CONHCH3?

Tags: lewis-structure

Chemical formula: $\ce{CH3CONHCH3}$

How could I draw the Lewis structure so that oxygen and nitrogen have a full octet? Currently, I have $\ce{CH3-C=O-NH-CH3}$.

Comment: The oxygen is doubly bonded to the carbon, and not bonded to the nitrogen.

Answer (score 1):

The part you get wrong is just like what Lighthart says, the oxygen is double bonded to carbon and not with nitrogen. Therefore, the nitrogen will be to bonded with the carbon. Second, you have a mistake when you write the first one as $\ce{CH_3}$. This is because it's carbon which bonded with the other carbon and not hydrogen. So the proper lewis structure will be like the picture below. [image]